# casperjs fill input based on his xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath, casperjs

I have many inputs and forms on my page without id, class or name. I have xpath of each instead. Is it possible to fill any input based on this? I can't change html to add anything.
I prefer way without jQuery, but for now anything is good, because i get stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.sendKeys(x('your_x_path', 'Text to fill in'));
});
```

Comment: with little fix: this.sendKeys(x('your_x_path'**),**'text'); it works

Comment: okay cool thank you, I was just going off of memory :)  Also in case you even run into the problem of hitting the return key you can put 'action' as your text and it fires the enter key.  i just recently learned that.